# `set_index()` does not sort index?

Tags: python, sorting, dask

Concatenating this dask DataFrame to this pandas DataFrame and using set_index to sort index does not result in a sorted index. Is this normal?

```py
    from dask import dataframe as dd
    import pandas as pd

    a=list('aabbccddeeffgghhi')
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a),
                      index = pd.date_range(start='2010/01/01', end='2010/02/01', periods=len(a))).reset_index()
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)

    a2=list('aabbccddeef')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a2),
                       index = pd.date_range(start='2020/01/01',end='2020/01/06', periods=len(a2))).reset_index()

    ddf2 = dd.concat([ddf, df2]).set_index('index')
    ddf2.compute()
```

```sh
                         a
    index                 
    2010-01-01 00:00:00  a
    2010-01-02 22:30:00  a
    2010-01-04 21:00:00  b
    2010-01-06 19:30:00  b
    2010-01-08 18:00:00  c
    2010-01-10 16:30:00  c
    2010-01-12 15:00:00  d
    2010-01-14 13:30:00  d
    2010-01-16 12:00:00  e
    2010-01-18 10:30:00  e
    2010-01-20 09:00:00  f
    2010-01-22 07:30:00  f
    2010-01-24 06:00:00  g
    2010-01-26 04:30:00  g
    2010-01-28 03:00:00  h
    2010-01-30 01:30:00  h
    2010-02-01 00:00:00  i
    2020-01-01 00:00:00  a
    2020-01-01 12:00:00  a
    2020-01-02 00:00:00  b
    2020-01-02 12:00:00  b
    2020-01-03 00:00:00  c
    2020-01-03 12:00:00  c
    2020-01-04 00:00:00  d
    2020-01-04 12:00:00  d
    2020-01-05 00:00:00  e
    2020-01-05 12:00:00  e
    2020-01-06 00:00:00  f
```

Please, do I do something the wrong way?

Comment: Here I do not see the problem. The index is already sorted. Maybe you though both dataframes apply from the same year but no (2010 then 2020)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is completly normal because most pandas operations don not assume a sorted index, some do though.

In dask dataframes you must apply
ddf2 = dd.concat([ddf, df2]).set_index('index', sorted = True).

By the way, your data is already properly sorted by index. Regard the years (2010, 2020)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, you are completely right, I feel dumb here ah ah. I thought both have been with year 2020.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, I dare to ask a new question as a comment. If I want to sort an index that is already an index, is it possible in Dask? I have been through different similar SO questions, and it seems the only way is 1st to reset that index, then set it again to have it sorted. Would you mbe aware maybe of a lesss awkward way to do?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try removing "reset_index" in both dataframes and the "set_index" in the Dask Dataframe. It should work.

Comment: ok, thanks. I would have thought there was a 'direct' sort, instead or reset/set method.
Thanks, have a good evening, bests!

Answer (score 1):

Try sort_index to sort.  Set index is just to set the index, doesn't force a resorting.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

Comment: Hi,   `set_index`is applied to a dask dataframe, not a pandas dataframe.